# Rust is skipping over for loop

Tags: for-loop, rust

I am fairly new to rust and am just trying to make a hangman game to help me learn the language. I have made a for loop that checks to see if the character I entered is in a vector of all the past characters I have guessed. But when running through it just keeps asking for the letter again, after going through the debugger it juts completely skips over the for loop completely.

I am using vscode with lldb to debug.

Can anyone lend a hand to either explain to me or help me work out why it isn't working.

```
use rand::random;

fn take_input(pre_guessed: &mut std::vec::Vec<char>) -> char{
    let mut run = true;

    print!("Enter letter: ");
    let mut temp_guess = String::new();
    let guess_char = match std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut temp_guess){
        Ok(_) => temp_guess.chars().next().expect("Could not convert guess to char"),
        Err(_) => '>'
    };
    println!();
    
    for i in pre_guessed.iter(){  // THIS IS THE FOR LOOP THAT IS SKIPPED OVER
        if *i == guess_char{
            run = false;
        }
    }

    if run == false{
        pre_guessed.push(guess_char);
        guess_char
    } else {
        take_input(pre_guessed)
    }
    
}

fn get_word() -> String {
    // goes to a text file and gets a word
}

fn check_correct(guessed_vec: &std::vec::Vec<char>) -> bool{
    let mut complete = true;
    for i in guessed_vec.iter(){
        if *i == '-'{
            complete = false;
        }
    }

    complete

}

fn main() {
    let word_to_guess = get_word();
    println!("{}", word_to_guess);
    let mut encoded_word = vec!['-'; word_to_guess.len()];

    let mut guessed = false;

    let mut guessed_letters: std::vec::Vec<char> = Vec::new();
    let mut wrong_letters: std::vec::Vec<char> = Vec::new();

    while guessed == false{
        println!("Guessed letters: {:?}", wrong_letters);
        for i in encoded_word.iter(){
            print!("{}", i);
        }
        println!();

        let guess = take_input(&mut guessed_letters);
        let mut temp_count = 0;
        let mut temp_match = false;
        for i in word_to_guess.chars(){
            if guess == i{
                encoded_word[temp_count] = i;
                temp_match = true
            }
            temp_count += 1;
        }

        if temp_match == false{
            wrong_letters.push(guess);
        }

        guessed = check_correct(&guessed_letters)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `guessed_letters` starts empty.
- The only thing that adds to it is `pre_guessed.push(guess_char)` when `run == false`.
- `run` starts `true`.
- The only thing that sets it to `false` is when `*i == guess_char` for any element `i` of `pre_guessed` (which is `guessed_letters`).

`guessed_letters` can only become nonempty when `run` is false, and `run` can only become false when `guessed_letters` is nonempty.

It looks like you meant:

```rust
if run {  // no == false
    pre_guessed.push(guess_char);
    guess_char
} else {
    take_input(pre_guessed)
}
```